# No such file or directory when trying to configure and install NodeJS using the tar.gz file (running ./configure not working)

Tags: node.js, installation, tar

I'm trying to install NodeJS and Karma. I initially went here: https://nodejs.org/en/ and installed the mature and dependable version. I then extracted the tar.gz file to my Downloads folder. According to here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/328681/installing-the-latest-node-js-mongodb the next step to install NodeJS would be to run `./configure`, right? I tried running `./configure` but I get an error from the terminal saying:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

What is the next step I have to take in order to correctly install NodeJS?

I am using Lubuntu. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm new to using Linux and NodeJS, it will be helpful if the down voters point me in the right direction.

Comment: What directory are you in when executing `./configure` ? Use `pwd` to find out

Comment: @chedabob I'm in the directory of the extracted folder. In my directory, there is a bin, include, lib and share folder with a CHANGELOG.md, LICENSE and README.md file. Any idea where the ./configure file is located for NodeJS?

Comment: Try extracting it again because there should definitely be a lot more in that folder

Comment: @chedabob I just extracted it again and the same things are inside the extracted folder. The tar.gz file is called node-v4.2.4-linux-x86.tar.gz and I downloaded it straight from the link I provided above. Are you able to download it on your computer and see if there are different things in your downloaded folder?

Comment: Ah, your instructions are for installing from source, but you've downloaded the Linux-x86 binary. Use this one: https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.4/node-v4.2.4.tar.gz

Comment: @chedabob Thanks for the help, that worked. You can put it down as the answer and I will check it off if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instructions are for installing from source, but you've downloaded the Linux-x86 binary. Use this one: nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.4/node-v4.2.4.tar.gz